# Servlet filter not working when using browser prev / forward page

Tags: servlets, filter, servlet-filters

i'm trying to filter every page request in my web app. So, i made some **Filter Class** that implements **Filter**.

I write some notifier code `(System.out.println("FILTERED!"))` in `doFilter()` function.

If i navigate page using normal navigation (with redirect, or some action) the notifier code is invoked. But when i try to navigate with browser prev /  next page button, the notifier code didn't called.

Is there some way how to make the Filter work with this condition ?

Thanks

Comment: Using redirect, you are triggering a new request to server.Hence filter gets called. 
Wheras clicking on browser prev/next doesn't trigger server side activity. So, in this case filter won't get
executed. I really wonder if such a mechanism exist.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your browser does not reload the page, it just uses its cache.

You may want to check that using the developer tools of your browser, in the network panel. If it says "using cache" or "cached" that's it.

You can also force the browser to reload the page, using this HTTP header:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
```